"Dynamic Date Scroll Wheel" Testing With Selenium & Python
I'm doing some web testing on a website (Pet Insurer - https://quote.petsy.com.au) and I came across a Dynamic Date Scroll Wheel.
My Goal: I am parsing a breed name and age in a dictionary, and I want to have the date on the website to match my age in the dictionary.
# Pet Breeds and Ages
pet_breed = {
'Cavadoodle': 4,
'Japanese Shiba Inu': 3,
}
I want to take the parsed age in the dictionary and subtract form current year. The date for the Cavadoodle would read as follows: 01-01-2020
I would also like to default the day and month to -01 as this makes it easier for calculations.
This would also have to be iterated for every breed after filling out an entire quote form.
Therefore, the date would have to update accordingly.
My Problem: I am unable to get the correct selectors for these web elements and I also need assistance with structuring the code as I'm new to Python and Selenium - I have built similar testers before, but not with a date scroll wheel.
My Question: Can anyone please assist?
